# What is the difference between retq and ret?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

Let's consider the following program, which computes an unsigned square of the argument:

```
.global foo
.text
foo:
    mov %rdi, %rax
    mul %rdi
    ret
```

This is properly compiled by `as`, but disassembles to

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
   3:   48 f7 e7                mul    %rdi
   6:   c3                      retq
```

Is there any difference between `ret` and `retq`?

Comment: `retq` is explicit about the operand size, but it's the same instruction.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In long (64-bit) mode, you return (`ret`) by popping a quadword address from the stack to `%rip`.

In 32-bit mode, you return (`ret`) by popping a dword address from the stack to `%eip`.

Some tools like `objdump -d` call the first one `retq`. It's just a name, the instruction encoding is the same either way (`C3`).

Comment: Does the stack pointer `rsp` gets updated when `retq`/`ret` is executed? Or that has to be done manually?

Comment: Obviously. It does pop, after all.

Comment: @stillanoob the `ret` instruction does two things: (1) pops the stack (which modifies `rsp` by subtracting 4 or 8 from it) (2) alters the `rip` (because the popped value goes into the `rip`).

Comment: push reduces the value of `%rsp`/`%esp`, pop increases the value of it. So `ret` increases the value of `%rsp` by 8 on 64 bit and of `%esp` by 4 bytes for 32 bit.