# How to do a relative jmp to a label in AT&T syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

In assembly if I write (at&t syntax, x86-64):

```
jmpq 0x4(%rip)
```

Then it jumps to 4+rip

But to where it jumps if I write:

```
jmpq label(%rip)
```

Where label = 4?

I'm confused because it can be the same answer or the same as movq where we move label and **NOT** label + rip.

Comment: If `label` is defined as a constant e.g. using `.equ` then it will behave exactly as if you used `4`. Otherwise the assembler will adjust the offset. Note this works the same for `mov`.

Comment: @Jester sorry I meant if label is a label like this label: in .text

Comment: @CherryDT why you added both? in mov it ignore rip...

Answer (score 2):

To do a normal relative jump that results in RIP = label, **use `jmp label`**.
The assembler calculates the relative displacement.

(And yes, you must use `jmp` not `jmpq`.  [An operand-size suffix for `jmp` implies an indirect jump in AT&T syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386736/what-is-jmpl-instruction-in-x86/54393149#54393149), unlike with `calll` / `callq`, which is an insane and confusing bad design.)

Relative direct jumps work the same as they have since 8086, and don't have anything to do with the RIP-relative data addressing mode that was new in x86-64. ([How do RIP-relative variable references like "[RIP + _a]" in x86-64 GAS Intel-syntax work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54745872/how-do-rip-relative-variable-references-like-rip-a-in-x86-64-gas-intel-sy) also covers how the AT&T syntax works for `4(%rip)` vs. `label(%rip)` for data addressing.)

You don't want to load a new RIP from a function pointer, so don't use a memory addressing mode.  A relative `jmp` doesn't access memory itself; the memory at `label` only gets accessed by code-fetch after the `jmp` finishes.  (Real CPUs are pipelined with branch prediction and stuff, but still maintain the *illusion* of instructions fully executing before the next one starts, e.g. a relative `jmp` to an unmapped page can fully execute without itself faulting, only the next code-fetch operation faults with saved RIP = the new location.)

> Then `jmpq 0x4(%rip)` jumps to `4+rip`

No, it doesn't.  If you actually assemble that, it warns `indirect jmp without '*'`.  Disassembly shows

```
ff 25 04 00 00 00       jmp    *0x4(%rip)
```

i.e. it *loads a pointer from memory* into RIP, from the qword that starts 4 bytes after the end of the `jmp` instruction.  It doesn't set RIP = RIP+4, that would be `jmp .+2 + 4` (because a short jump is 2 bytes long, or if you put a label after the jmp, `jmp end_of_insn + 4`)

Comment: So to summarize this will jump to what: jmpq my_int_var(%rip)? where my_int_var=4?

Comment: @Dan: You mean if you used `my_int_var=4` in the asm source, which is the same thing as `.equ my_int_var, 4` to set the symbol address to `4`?  Turns out that's the same as doing `jmpq 4(%rip)`, rather than using a RIP-relative addressing mode to reach absolute address 4.  You can and should try this yourself with `gcc -c foo.s` && `objdump -drwC foo.o`.  It warns about an indirect jump without `*`.

Comment: @Dan: unless the definition of `my_int_var=4` appears after the `jmp` in the source, in which case you get a relocation in the object file, and upon linking you do get `401000:     ff 25 fe ef bf ff     jmp    *-0x401002(%rip)    # 4 <my_int_var>` which loads a pointer from address `4`, which it reached with a RIP-relative addressing mode.  GAS is weird like that I guess because it's a 1-pass (over the source) assembler.  [Distinguishing memory from constant in GNU as .intel\_syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39355188) is the basically the same issue.